# How do you find out names of parameters and data required by a objective function in a TMB .cpp file?

Tags: r, tmb

From the [TMB tutorial](https://github.com/kaskr/adcomp/wiki/Tutorial), one defines objective functions in a `.cpp` file, such that parameter names and names of model data structures are shared between the C++ function and what is called from R. For example, the `tutorial.cpp` file:

```
#include <TMB.hpp>                                // Links in the TMB libraries

template<class Type>
Type objective_function<Type>::operator() ()
{
  DATA_VECTOR(x);                                 // Data vector transmitted from R
  PARAMETER(mu);                                  // Parameter value transmitted from R
  PARAMETER(sigma);                               //                 

  Type f;                                         // Declare the "objective function" (neg. log. likelihood)
  f = -sum(dnorm(x,mu,sigma,true));               // Use R-style call to normal density

  return f;
}
```

After compilation and `dyn.load` one can call this function from R, however, you need to know that the data vector is named `x`, and that there are two parameter values `mu` and `sigma`. Is it possible to retrieve the names of these required objects some how from R?

Comment: I propose removing the rcpp tag from all (or most of) your questions as this is pretty much unrelated to Rcpp -- you just use it to get to your particular library of interest, here TMB,

Comment: There is no `TMB` tag at the moment, maybe this could be useful to better identify these questions. I do not have enough reputation for now to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of a function in the package that does this, but the function below might help you out;

```
    TMBsearch = function(path,what='parameter',class=FALSE){

    if(!missing(what) | length(what)>1) stop("What should be of length one")
    if(!(what %in% c('parameter','data','report','sdreport')))  stop("What should be parameter, data, report or sdreport")

     text = paste0(paste0(readLines(path), collapse = "\n"), "\n") # read the text from the cpp file
     start = unlist(gregexpr(pattern =toupper(what),text)) # starting position
     end.poss = unlist(gregexpr(pattern =')',text)) # possible end positions
     end = rep(NA,length(start))
     for(i in 1:length(start)){end[i] = end.poss[(end.poss-start[i]) > 0][1]} # actual end position
     textsub = substring(text,first=start,last=end) # extract the full PARAMETER/DATA_x(...) 
     found = gsub("[\\(\\)]", "", regmatches(textsub, gregexpr("\\(.*?\\)", textsub))) # get rid of the brackets

     if(class & what %in% c('parameter','data')){
       dataclass=tolower(gsub("_", "",gsub(".*PARAMETER\\s*|\\(.*", "", textsub)))
       dataclass[dataclass=='']="single value"
       names(found)=datatype
     }

     return(found)
}

TMBsearch(path=paste0(filename,'.cpp'), what='parameter')
```

"what" can either be 'parameter', 'data', 'report' or 'sdreport' but by default I made it parameter.

ADDITION: if class==TRUE than for parameter and data the class (matrix, array, etc.) is given as the name of each object.

Comment: in my edit, the combination of `function(..., what = c("parameter", "data", "report", "sdreport")` and `what = match.arg(what)` does what  you are doing with your `if ... stop ...` code, and defaults to `"parameter"` if nothing is supplied, but up to you what you want to do. Also `!missing(what)` is superfluous in your first if statement.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know who changed it and why exactly. I wasn't familiar with match.arg. Go ahead if you feel like it's better your way, it is indeed cleaner.  I just thought that the error message would be a little vague and I like the idea the options are given in the error.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Wave for your useful function. I just improved it a little to retrieve all types in a list if `what` has multiple arguments. I also had some remaining spaces in my names, so that I also added a `gsub`.

```
TMBsearch <- function(path, what = c('parameter', 'data', 'report', 'sdreport')) {
  res <- lapply(what, function(what) {
    # what <- match.arg(what)
    text <- paste0(paste0(readLines(path), collapse = "\n"), "\n") # read the text from the cpp file
    start <- unlist(gregexpr(pattern = toupper(what), text)) # starting position
    end.poss <- unlist(gregexpr(pattern = ')', text)) # possible end positions
    end <- rep(NA,length(start))
    for (i in 1:length(start)) {end[i] <- end.poss[(end.poss - start[i]) > 0][1]} # actual end position
    textsub <- substring(text, first = start, last = end) # extract the full PARAMETER/DATA_x(...) -> might be handy to now whether array or vector or...
    found <- gsub("[\\(\\)]", "", regmatches(textsub, gregexpr("\\(.*?\\)", textsub))) # get rid of the brackets
    found_nospace <- gsub(" ", "", found) # get rid of the spaces if some left
    return(found_nospace)
  })
  names(res) <- what
  res
}
```